# Move elements after sibling

Tags: jquery, dom, element, siblings

I have hundreds of

```
<div class="post">
```

next to eachother.

New elements are updated via AJAX and put on top of the existing ones.

Now there is a special

```
<div id="ad1">
```

that I want to always keep on nth place.

So I made that function:

```
$(".post").each(function() {
    if(cnt>2){
        $('#ad1').after(this);
    }
    cnt++;
});
```

It almost works, however, the elements that are moved after #ad1 are in reverse order, as the loop goes from 1 to n but the elements are always appended directly after #ad1.

Any input is highly welcome.

Thanks
Raphael

Comment: both answers work, but if I understand, they move the #ad1 which could pose problems with the adsense code in that div. So what's an elegant solution to move all but the first n elements before #ad1 after #ad1 without changing their order?

Comment: Added a second solution (untested).

Comment: Thank you! This code makes a copy of #ad1 every time it runs, so I see 3 instances after the 2nd run... don't understand why as nextUntil is documented to get all the elements up to, but not including to the selector??

Comment: fixed -- I was using the wrong 'after' method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip the loop. Just one line of code should do it (run it after you add any new element to the top):

```
$('.post').eq(n).before($('#ad1')); // don't forget .eq is zero-based
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/MD4b2/2/

Or to move the rest below the ad:

```
$('.post').eq(n-1).nextUntil('#ad1').insertAfter($('#ad1'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/MD4b2/

Comment: Blazemonger, this is pretty crazy... thank you so much! I hope it's ok with Google Adsense TOS to keep my ad above the fold like that?

Comment: Your 2nd approach seems wonderful as (if I understand correct) it doesn't move the #ad1 around, but moves the .post so that #ad1 stays at position n?

Comment: If that's the case this should be 100% safe with adsense, unfortunately I can't upvote because I have only 11 reputation so far :(

Comment: Just accept your favorite answers by clicking the check mark near the vote button. This encourages others to work with you in the future.

Comment: oh... ok... didn't see that, it was too small for my eyes ;) Thank you again! Send me a PM with your PayPal address and I'll send you some bucks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use nth-child here:

```
$("div.post:nth-child("+n+")").before($('#ad1'));
```

Comment: Sorry, submitted to early. As you can read above, I load adsense ads in that #ad1 div. Isn't your and Blazemongers way always making a new instance of that div (like removing and readding)? I think if that's the case it will not work with adsense in it and I fear to try it out...

Comment: No it wont create a new instance.  It just copies that instance and put it before div post.

Comment: and that won't interfere with Google Adsense code inside of it?

Comment: As the div instance is just moved to different place.  I dont think it should be a problem.